# Learning Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am started to work on sharepoint development. I have to create webparts and host it in sharepoint. What could be good starting point to understand the sharepoint architecure. Any suggestion on good books or blogs to read to get started quickly.

Comment: Does anyone know if Sharepoint Online (by MS) is a valid choice to quickly set-up a full SP environment in order to study SP (as a developer) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[www.sharepoint.net](http://www.sharepoint.net)

```
Microsoft Solution for SharePoint 2010 (Sahil Malik) its a great book
```

Answer (score 1):

### [MSDN SharePoint Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint)

I'd start at the [MSDN Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint) first.  It has a ton of tutorials, articles and samples to get you started quickly.  (And it's free.)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm to recommend one classic SP2010 book i.e. [Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742318.aspx)